# GAE/J OneToMany JPA Persistence Failure When Deployed

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, deployment, persistence, one-to-many

I am using Google App Engine with JPA to implement a one-to-many bidirectional relationship. Everything works just fine when I debug and test my application on my machine at home, but after I deploy it to the App Engine persistence seems to break down.

This is the model I have (stripped down for simplicity):

User.java:

```
@Entity
class User implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner",
               cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
               fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Book> books;

    public getBooks() { return this.books; }
}
```

Book.java:

```
@Entity
class Book implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User owner;

    private String name;
}
```

To create a new `User`:

```
User user = new User()

// This is done just for testing. It works fine.
user.getBooks().add(new Book("TEST"))

EntityManager em = /* ... */
EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();

try
{
    transaction.begin();
    em.persist(user);
    transaction.commit();
}

/* Exceptions handling. */

finally
{
    if (transaction.isActive())
        transaction.rollback();

    em.close();
}
```

And to add a book:

```
User user = /* ... */
Book book = new Book("A new book");

user.getBooks().add(book);

EntityManager em = /* ... */
EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();

try
{
    transaction.begin();
    /* user.getBooks().add(book);  - placing this here doesn't change anything */
    em.merge(user);
    transaction.commit();
}

/* Exceptions handling. */

finally
{
    if (transaction.isActive())
        transaction.rollback();

    em.close();
}
```

What I saw, before I added the 'test' book which is created along with the User, is that creation of the first book entity works just fine, but whenever I create *another* one, the previous one is somehow removed from the Datastore and is replaced by the new one which I just created (I can tell because of the books' names). So I cannot create more than one book for the same user.

I tried to see if I somehow messed up persistence of the Book entity, and for that reason I added the 'TEST' book. The problem persists, only that now I have the first book ("TEST") and I keep replacing the second book on the list whenever I try to add a new one.

Again, this doesn't happen when I debug my application, only after I deploy.

I tried calling `em.persist(book)` before the call to `em.merge(user)`, but that caused an exception saying the book's owner was already set when it was persisted and cannot be changed. I tried setting the relationship myself (like in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434853/jpa-onetomany-update)), but that caused a failed transaction when adding a book.

I'm not sure if its relevant, but the type of the 'books' column I see is `datastore_types.Key.from_path`, as in:

```
[datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'User', 9001L, u'Book', 1L, _app=u's~myapp'),
 datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'User', 9001L, u'Book', 2001L, _app=u's~myapp')]
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you!

Comment: Its a bidirectional relation yet you haven't set both sides of the relation. No reason why putting some operation on a DETACHED object inside a txn should make a difference ... the object is DETACHED after all. No idea what is this "somehow" ... you have a log which tells you all DB calls, for all of your persistence operations, so you have all info there to understand it

Comment: I have only the following warning when I add a new user: `com.google.appengine.datanucleus.MetaDataValidator warn: Meta-data warning for User.books: Error in meta-data for User.books : The datastore does not support joins and therefore cannot honor requests to place related objects in the default fetch group.  The field will be fetched lazily on first access.` I don't think the book objects are detached because I can see their properties in a JSP I redirect to.

Comment: BTW, the only logs I can see in the GAE's admin console are under 'Logs' and 'Admin Logs', both of which don't tell me anything about "all of my persistence operations" and/or my Datastore calls (those that are made from the application and not manually by me as an admin). Is there a setting to enable these detailed Datastore logs somehow?

Comment: The GAE docs refers to DataNucleus (used for persistence) which can use Log4j if you have it present otherwise JDK1.4 logging. Those are standard logging packages. When debugging something its normal to use DEBUG level logging, not WARN or above

Comment: OK, I've modified the code to set the book's owner inside the transaction to the value returned from `merge` (i.e. `book.setOwner(em.merge(user))`). This was because calling `book.setOwner(user)` outside of the transaction caused an exception saying that the owner of `book` is a different entity than the one attempted to set during the transaction. The problem persists, however - creation of a new book overrides the old one.

Comment: As said, the log tells you the datastore calls. Also the object lifecycle state (transient, detached, managed) defines what is persisted or attached.

Comment: I'm looking at the Datastore calls and these seem fine. there aren't any errors and the transaction completes. Still, each new book I add only replaces the previous one instead of being added to the list. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below:

```
User user = /* ... */
Book book = new Book("A new book");

book.setOwner(user);

EntityManager em = /* ... */
EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();

try{
    transaction.begin();
    em.persist(user);
    transaction.commit();

}finally{
    if (transaction.isActive())
        transaction.rollback();

    em.close();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. First of all because of the second call to `persist` on an already persisted `User`. Second, I switched it to a `merge` but obviously `user` doesn't know anything about `book` without a call to `books.add`...

I tried calling both `books.add` and `setOwner` before the transaction, but that doesn't work either since it creates a second attempt to set the book's owner when the call to `merge` is performed.